# Multiprocessing Pool: operation timed out

Tags: python, timeout, multiprocessing

I have this piece of code:

```
import urllib2, json, csv
import requests
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import numpy
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

def getTaxiTrips(date):
    """
    Gets the taxi trips occurred in NY from a starting date.
    :param date: (Y-m-d).
    :return: list of tuples (long, lat, drop off date).
    """
    today = str(datetime.date(datetime.now())).split('-')
    today_y = today[0]
    today_m = today[1]

    start = date.split('-')
    start_y = start[0]
    start_m = start[1]

    print start_m + "-" + start_y + " / " + today_m + "-" + today_y

    data = []
    y = int(start_y)
    m = int(start_m)
    while int(start_y) <= int(today_y):
        # Month transformation
        if m > 12:
            m %= 12
            y += 1

        mt = str(m) if m > 9 else '0' + str(m)
        # Green cabs
        if readCSV("https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/" + str(y) + \
                   "/green_tripdata_" + str(y) + "-" + mt + ".csv") is not None:
            data.append("https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/" + str(y) + \
                        "/green_tripdata_" + str(y) + "-" + mt + ".csv")

        # Yellow cabs
        if readCSV("https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/" + str(y) +
                   "/yellow_tripdata_" + str(y) + "-" + mt + ".csv") is not None:
            data.append("https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/" + str(y) +
                        "/yellow_tripdata_" + str(y) + "-" + mt + ".csv")

        if m == int(today_m):
            break
        m += 1

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(mps-1)
    result = pool.map(consumeTaxiData, data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return list(itertools.chain(*result))


def consumeTaxiData(url):
    """
    Given a url, reads its content and process its data.
    :param url: the url to be readen.
    :return: a list of tuples in the form (long, lat, hour).
    """
    print "Processing", url
    points = []

    data = readCSV(url)
    for line in data:
        latitude = line.get('dropoff_latitude', None)
        if latitude is None:
            latitude = line.get('Dropoff_latitude', None)

        longitude = line.get('dropoff_longitude', None)
        if longitude is None:
            longitude = line.get('Dropoff_longitude', None)

        time = line.get('tpep_dropoff_datetime', None)
        if time is None:
            time = line.get('Lpep_dropoff_datetime', None)

        if time is not None:
            time = datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            if latitude is not None and longitude is not None and time >= datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') and \
                    time.weekday():
                time = roundTime(time, roundTo=60 * 60).hour
                points.append((float(longitude), float(latitude), time))

    return points

def readCSV(url):
    """
    Read a csv file.
    :param url: url to be read.
    :return: an array of dictionaries.
    """
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return csv.DictReader(response, delimiter=',')
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        return None

def roundTime(dt=None, roundTo=60):
   """
   Round a datetime object to any time laps in seconds
   :param dt: datetime.datetime object, default now.
   :param roundTo: closest number of seconds to round to, default 1 minute.
   :return: the rounded time.
   """
   if dt == None : dt = datetime.now()
   seconds = (dt - dt.min).seconds
   rounding = (seconds+roundTo/2) // roundTo * roundTo
   return dt + timedelta(0, rounding-seconds, -dt.microsecond)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mps = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    date = str(datetime.date(datetime.now()) - timedelta(31*8))
    print "-----> Inital date:", date

    print "-----> Getting taxi data..."
    taxi_dropoffs = getTaxiTrips(date)
    print len(taxi_dropoffs), "taxi trips"
```

That was working just fine for these data:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/green_tripdata_2015-06.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/yellow_tripdata_2015-06.csv
```

Now that I'm trying to process more data:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/green_tripdata_2015-06.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/green_tripdata_2015-07.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/green_tripdata_2015-08.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/yellow_tripdata_2015-08.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/yellow_tripdata_2015-07.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/yellow_tripdata_2015-06.csv
https://storage.googleapis.com/tlc-trip-data/2015/green_tripdata_2015-09.csv
```

I keep receiving this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noiseInference.py", line 489, in <module>
    taxi_dropoffs = getTaxiTrips(date)
  File "noiseInference.py", line 300, in getTaxiTrips
    result = pool.map(consumeTaxiData, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Because each `.csv` file is big and I'm processing a lot of them, I was expecting the processing method to take some time. However, the processing is being terminated. How do I solve this issue?

The data comes from here: http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml

Comment: 1.6GB is not HUGE. That's kind of like much if you really need to use CSV... but no one should try to use CSV if the resulting CSV is 1.6GB. But still, 1.6GB is not really much.

Comment: I see, @MarcusMüller. The thing is that this how the data is stored here http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml.

Comment: Well, the point is that possibly the duration of your download is the problematic thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `multiprocessing.Pool` is usually quite misleading.

The traceback:

```
  return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
  raise self._value
  socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Shows the `map_async.get` raising an error stored in its `_value` attribute. This attribute simply contains the error which was raised in the process.
The error is pretty clear: the socket operation is timing out.

To better see what's the problem I'd suggest you to reproduce it outside the `multiprocessing.Pool.map_async`.